# Spring Boot WebMvcTest returns 302 instead of 401 for GET methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-security, jwt

I have an application with REST endpoints that are secured with `JWT` authentication (external resource server). After upgrading my project from spring-boot 2.2.7 to 2.4.3 some of the `WebMvcTest` integration tests are failing. Specifically, test cases for `GET` requests without `JWT` tokens - previously they would return `401 UNAUTHORIZED`, now they return `302 REDIRECT` to `http://localhost/oauth2/authorization/keycloak`.

```java
@Test
void shouldNotAllowAccessForUnauthenticatedUsers() throws Exception {
    // given
    var params = createParams();

    // when / then
    mockMvc.perform(get(MY_URI)
            .params(params)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(new byte[0]))
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
}
```

No custom web security configuration is imported, just `@WebMvcTest`, `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` plus `@ContextConfiguration` for relevant controller and mapper beans.

`POST` methods in tests without authentication return `403` (as before the upgrade). This problem occurs only in tests - when application is running, calling any endpoint without the token results in `401`.

Is there a way to configure `WebMvcTest` to return `401` instead of `302`?

Comment: What version of Keyclock are you using? Have you verified that it's compatible with Spring Boot 2.4.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andy Wilkinson's question inspired me to look deeper into this, since no Keycloak adapter is really added as an explicit dependency (only `spring-boot-starter-security`, `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`), but `keycloak` is mentioned in the config here:

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ...
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: ...
            client-secret: ...
            authorization-grant-type: ...
            scope: ...
        provider:
          keycloak:
            authorization-uri: ...
            token-uri: ...
```

Requests for app's endpoints are authenticated with JWT tokens from the issuer-uri, but HTTP client calls to other services are authenticated using client registration in Keycloak (for service-to-service authentication).

Anyway, I believe this change of behavior after upgrade is due to a feature introduced in [Spring Boot 2.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes), specifically: "OAuth2 parameter binding in `@WebMvcTest`". Auto-configuration for OAuth2 is now included in `@WebMvcTest` which resulted in this test trying to redirect to keycloak using the client configuration (which in runtime is used only for service-to-service).

I fixed the issue by annotating the test class with:

```java
@ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude = {OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.class, OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

(Resource server config had to be excluded as well to handle mocked JWT properly.)

Maybe someone will find this helpful.

Comment: Dude!  This is the EXACT problem I was having and your solution worked.  I owe you a beer or two.